# Speakers about to explode (loud SOUND) when I raise the volume on my interface and the mic is ON. why?

Tags: recording, studio

I always have to switch off the speakers and use the headphones instead, while I record. Is there a way to avoid that? Because I've seen plenty of people online recording stuff with the Mic in front of the speakers, and they were ON, music was coming out from them. HOW CAN I DO THAT?

Comment: A straightforward answer would be to have the music coming out of the speakers, but set up your software so that the mic sound doesn't come out of the speakers...

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a [feedback loop (also named howlround or larsen (in a few places apparently))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback): if your speaker are outputting the sound from your mic then your mic pick it up and it is coming back to the speakers.

This will continue and if the gain of this evil loop is over one, the loudspeakers output level will increase, increase, until it is unbearable…

There are a few solutions though:

- if your mic is directional, place it a way so that it does not pick the sound from the speaker
- disable direct monitoring, so that the sound recorded by the mic won't be outputted by the speakers (as said by topo Reinstate Monica).

Hope it helps…

Comment: Never heard this called a Larsen in 50 years of being in the business… learn something new every day - or alternatively, you could just call it feedback or howlround, same as everybody else ;)

Comment: Haha, in France that how it is called, from the guy who discovered it. That is true that I already got a few confused reactions from international music mate… I'll edit!

Comment: Larsen: “Wow, I just discovered this horrible squealing sound while messing with a microphones and speakers, I think I’ll name it after myself!” ;-) +1

Comment: Back in those days, I guess it was a bit more easy to let your name on an effect/theory ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re talking about feedback, a loud squealing noise. When sound comes out of a speaker and it goes into a microphone that is connected to that speaker it causes a continuous loop of very loud and unpleasant sound that can be either a low hum or a high pitched squeal.

You can record a speaker with a microphone but it cannot be the speaker you are using for playback. In order to record say an electric guitar coming out of a speaker with a mic it should be a separate dedicated amplifier or speaker just for the guitar and not your studio playback speakers.  When recording with speakers and microphones it is best to use headphones anyway because if you record with your speakers on your other tracks will also get recorded into the microphone, plus you still run the risk of feedback even with a separate speaker.